# MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, webview

I'm using a webview in my Facebook Messenger chatbot for payment and MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser is supposed to close the webview window and return the user back to the chat flow - but it doesn't work.  The docs say it works and I tried to do exactly what they said; apparently I am missing something.  Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

I am hosting the webview in a rails 4.2 app, so the js is in a separate file.  I'm using jquery to handle the event.  Here is the code:

the button in the view that should trigger the action (using slim):

    `button type="button" class="chat-button" id="closeButton" Done!`

the .js file:

```
$(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));

$(function() {
  $("#closeButton").click(function() {
    alert("hit me");
    MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(
      function success() {},
      function error(err) {
        alert(err)
      }
    );
    return false;
  });
});

window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    alert("js sdk finished loading");
};
```

Note that both alerts do fire, one when the sdk is loaded, and one when the button is clicked.  But the webview does not close as advertised.  BTW - the error returned is 2071010.  What am I missing?

Comment: I have heard from another user that this does work for them.  I must have something in my environment that is preventing this from working.

Comment: this works on Android and iOS ONLY. Also, the iOS version of the messenger app, must be the latest one or this might not work on iOS as well.

Answer (score 3):

**messenger_extensions** needs to be set to true.

```
"attachment": {
    "type": "template",
    "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "Check this out!",
        "buttons": [
            {
                "type": "web_url",
                "url": "https://yourpage.com",
                "title": "Some Title",
                "webview_height_ratio": "compact",
                "messenger_extensions": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work in your code?
I get this error when I add the `whitelisted_domains` field to the a button:

```OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Invalid keys \\"whitelisted_domains\\" were found in param \\"name_placeholder[buttons][0]```

Comment: So, removing `whitelisted_domains` works, and adding `messenger_extensions` definitely helps too ;)

I added `messenger_extensions` via the [Messenger Profile API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting/) and everything now works as expected.

Comment: You're right... I had done an update to the code that didn't propagate yet when I tested it.  The command line is the way to go on the whitelisting to go into the settings in Facebook. The original example I had with the whitelist in the buttons config causes it to break.  I updated the example.

Comment: Just a quick handy tip in case anyone's still Googling this: you can now whitelist domains through Facebook itself in your page settings, rather than having to use the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I filed an issue with Facebook and they had just resolved another issue that resolved this one also.  A new release of Messenger on IOS and my code suddenly worked as advertised.  Thanks to all for your interest.